# use prettier to resolve no-duplicate-imports eslint error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

eslint has `no-duplicate-imports` https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-duplicate-imports which shows error or warning for importing multiple modules from same path duplicate lines.

ie.

```
import { testModule } from '../file'
import { otherModule } from '../file'
```

makes you resolve as:

```
import { testModule, otherModule } from '../file'
```

How would you accomplish this with an existing prettier plugin, or any other way where `onSave` it resolves this for you, to avoid having to fix this manually.

Comment: try running the linter with the `--fix` flag.